# How to open socket in my client for Gmail?

Tags: android-emulator

I developing one App in that i'm creating my own client through which i want to access gmail?
 or how to open session?

Answer (score 0):

your question is very vague. Take a look at the gmail API and then post more specific questions (if you find the documentation confusing).

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/